# Bloomberg Data License return 0.000 YAS_OAS_SPRD

Tags: python, overriding, bloomberg, blpapi

This is the result of my BDP CALL

bdp("AU3FN0051587 Corp", 'YAS_OAS_SPRD')

**arguments**

isin=AU3FN0051587 Corp

field=YAS_OAS_SPRD

**Result**
.000

The answer is not equals to the value in the terminal. Is there a reason?

Thank you

Comment: Have you asked the help desk?

Comment: Can we see the code where you call this function?

Comment: bdp("AU3FN0051587 Corp", 'YAS_OAS_SPRD')

Comment: By 'see the code' I meant something that can be reproduced (eg including import statements etc).

Comment: https://github.com/leafyoung/Bloomerg_DLWS/blob/master/dlws-bbg.py
But you need a certificate from Datalicense Bloomberg

Comment: I’m currently using data license (soap protocol). I would like to know why this field is causing some troubles. All other fields are giving the best result. I tried multiple ways to solve this problem, including overriding the pricing source but none of them were successful. 
The problem appears only in certain Isin. There are 3 types of return in my tests (Correct value, 0 and NA)
For example, AU3FN0051587 returns 0.
CA31430WHQ02 returns NA.
CA31430WAB06 returns the correct value.

Comment: Ah, was kind of assuming you were using the client-based DAPI interface (which runs on the same machine as the Terminal). I'm afraid I don't have experience with this method. Fwiw, I get the correct value using `xbbg` in Python. As @assylias says, if you can reliably replicate this, then maybe approach your Bloomi rep for help.

Comment: This could be a permissioning or settings issue (DL uses the settings of a given user or terminal which may yield different results), Best to ask Bloomberg to be honest (you can raise the issue on the data licence portal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask to bloomberg.

Unfortunately, rules on AU3FN0051587 block it in Data License hence you don't get any value returned for YAS_OAS_SPRD. Same rules allow CA31430WAB06 and hence correct value is returned. The rule is recognized by a field in FLDS -> CALC_TYP.

[More information is available here](http://www.betandbetter.com/photos_forum/1418754609.pdf)